# How does android deal with playing video given its memory constraints?

Tags: android, memory, video, sd-card

I'm curious if someone can point me to (or just describe) how, given that an Android application has an extremely limited memory space to play with (I think it's around 20 megs), a video player can load and play videos that are an order of magnitude or more larger in size.  Is the app loading the video in some sort of chunks?

I ask because I have an app that has some video assets embedded and the app has grown to be about 80 megs and is just a total monster for compiling and debugging (without the assets the app would only be about 2 megs), and I was thinking that I should just remove the assets and have them download on the side and sit on the sdcard, rather than within the apk, but I'm worried that loading them and playing them at run time will bust through the app's memory allotment, and was hoping someone can shed some light on what my options are.

TIA

Comment: They buffer the video in manageable chunks, yes. Even if your videos are GBs in size, you won't hit a memory wall using standard video playing APIs. Downloading the videos outside the apk is still a good idea, though. If I had to download a new 80MB file for each incremental upgrade, I'd probably just uninstall instead.

Comment: when you say "standard video playing apis" do you mean that I can just make a URI out of the path to the local file and hand it to the VideoView in my Activity, and it will handle it as gracefully as it does when I hand it a URI pointing to an internal apk resource? (which is how I was hoping it would work).

Comment: Yes, using `setVideoURI` or `setVideoPath` will work.

Comment: awesome... you should post this as the answer so that I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They buffer the video in manageable chunks, yes. Even if your videos are GBs in size, you won't hit a memory wall using standard video playing APIs. You can use the standard calls to `setVideoURI` or `setVideoPath` to point to the file and it will handle it from there. The same works for `MediaPlayer` in general if you're not using a `VideoView`

Downloading the videos outside the apk is still a good idea, though. If I had to download a new 80MB file for each incremental upgrade, I'd probably just uninstall instead. If you don't want to host them yourself, look into the supplemental apk option.

Answer (score 1):

You can take your game into the native layer where you can bypass this limit. Take a look at a blog I wrote http://jnispot.blogspot.com/2012/10/jnindk-arrays-bitmaps-and-games-oh-my.html

Comment: this doesn't immediately address my problem but I'm +1(ing) it anyway cause it's a very interesting solution to the memory boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is what video apps do, but you can actually increase the memory beyond the normal limit by using malloc statements in native code.  This bypasses the normal max of around 20 MB.

I have only used this for encryption on android devices where AES encryption needs rather karger amounts of memory when dealing with large encrypted files (even around 10MB files).

Comment: sorry... I don't understand what you mean by "native code"... how does one access malloc in Java?  Or are you saying I should bypass java and write my apps in C somehow?

Comment: You can write native code using the NDK and can even combine java and C in apps.  Videos will normally use buffers as someone else suggested but there is a possibility of increasing memory limits using the NDK.

Comment: This problem in particular is a video problem, but this is a very interesting idea that I will definitely look into when I have a moment (read: never) :)